# Skip commit if no files are changed in git2/libgit2

Tags: rust, libgit2, git2-rs

I'm using the `git2` crate which wraps `libgit2`.

I'm adding files to the index whether or not they are changed to stage them for committing.

If there are no files changed in the repo, when I commit, I get an empty commit, that I'd like to avoid. I thought calling `index.is_empty()` would indicate no changes, but I have a count returned from `index.len()`.

I'd be fine resetting the index or avoid adding files to the index if they are unchanged.

How can I avoid inserting an empty commit? I know the `git` CLI has support for this, and can disable it with `--allow-empty`.

Answer (score 1):

I can iterate through the index entries and look for ones that have not changed by calling `status_file` against the `Repository`

```
let repo: Repository = ...;
let index: Index = ...;
let changed_files = index
    .iter()
    .flat_map(|e| String::from_utf8(e.path))
    .map(|e| PathBuf::from(OsString::from(e)))
    .flat_map(|p| repo.status_file(&p))
    .any(|s| s != Status::CURRENT);
```

Comment: Does `status_file` really perform a status? (Meaning diffing both the working directory with the index _and_ the index with `HEAD`.) If so, you'll get false positives for unstaged changes in the working directory. In addition, it's inefficient since you're calling status for each file. I would recommend instead doing a diff of the index with `HEAD`; if the diff is empty then there are no changes to commit.

Comment: @EdwardThomson an example of that would be amazing

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm not super familiar with the git2 rust bindings. But you'll want to get the repository's [head](https://cmsd2.github.io/rust-docs/codelauf/git2/struct.Repository.html#method.head), [peel](https://cmsd2.github.io/rust-docs/codelauf/git2/struct.Reference.html#method.peel) that to a commit, get the commit's [tree](https://cmsd2.github.io/rust-docs/codelauf/git2/struct.Commit.html#method.tree), and then call [Diff::tree_to_index](https://cmsd2.github.io/rust-docs/codelauf/git2/struct.Diff.html#method.tree_to_index), passing the repository's head's tree as the old tree.